# Idiom for doing something twice in C++

Tags: c++, idioms

Is there a common idiom for doing something twice, as in the following situation?

```
    for ( int i = 0; i < num_pairs; i++ ) {
        cards.push_back( Card(i) );
        cards.push_back( Card(i) );
    }
```

I have a feeling that there's a clearer way than introducing a new loop variable counting from 0 to 1, especially since it isn't used except for counting.

```
    for ( int i = 0; i < num_pairs; i++ )
        for ( int j = 0; j < 2; j++ )
            cards.push_back( Card(i) );
```

(`Card` is just some class I made up and not relevant to the question.)

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by *idiom*? What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: value readability and maintainability

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the first example. Idioms are useful for more complex things and are meant to make programs more understandable and correct. What you're asking is a fairly straight-forward thing, there doesn't need to be an idiom for it.

Comment: If you had a vector or something like that I would recommend you to use `std::for_each(start, end, []() {cards.push_back(Card(i));});`

Comment: Check the last example in this page: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/for_each.html

Comment: You could say `for (int dummy : { 0, 1 }) { /* do stuff */ }`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've got a few suggestions. See the *last* for my recommendation:

1. In my opinion `insert(it,` *`N`*`, value)` beats `std::fill_n`:

   ```
   for ( int i = 0; i < num_pairs; i++ ) {
       cards.insert(cards.end(), 2, Card(i) );
   }
   ```
2. If order isn't important, you could just generate the cards once, and duplicate **after** the fact

   ```
   std::copy(cards.begin(), cards.end(), std::back_inserter(cards));
   ```
3. Using a dirty lambda and integer division trick. **Warning** this has the hallmark of a premature optimization: reduces readability for no good reason.

   ```
   std::vector<Card> cards(num_pairs * 2);
   int i = 0;
   std::generate_n(cards.begin(), num_pairs, [&i] () { return Card(i++/2); });
   ```

   (assumes `Card` is *default-constructible*. If not, use `cards.back_inserter()`)
4. ### My recommendation

   The following wins in both performance and expression of intent:

   ```
   std::vector<Card> cards;
   cards.reserve(num_pairs*2);
   for (int i = 0; i < num_pairs; ++i)
   {
       cards.emplace_back(i);
       cards.emplace_back(i);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 10):

You probably want to use the `fill_n` function in `<algorithm>`

```
for ( int i = 0; i < num_pairs; i++ )
    std::fill_n(std::back_inserter(cards), 2, Card(i));
```

Comment: Would this call the Card constructor once or twice?

Comment: Then unfortunately it wouldn't be equivalent to the code I posted.

Comment: @Andreas It would call Card(int) (or whatever that signature is) once, and it would call the copy constructor twice probably.

Answer (score 6):

Personally I would just leave it how it is.  It looks clean, it's easy to understand, and it's quite readable. Just leave a comment mentioning why you do it twice (but you would do that no matter what).

Answer (score 1):

You are right about using expanding the inner loop into statements as using another loop only 2 iterations is going to be bad for performance. Due of the frequent `jumps`, the second one (nested loops) is going to perform slowly. Whether there will be any noticeable difference completely depends on the `num_pairs`.

So the first one is better for performance(however marginal the gain might be). This sort of expanding loops is called `loop unwinding/unrolling` in compiler's terminology. However, this term is not used at programming level as usually only compiler does that to make the code faster. `Idioms` are certain `design notions` that help programmers write better & efficient code and understand the language better.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this very often, write a little utility function:

```
template<class F>
void repeat(unsigned times, F callback) {
  while (times--) callback();
}

// ...

for (int i = 0; i < num_pairs; i++) {
  repeat(2, [&] { cards.push_back(Card(i)); });
}
```

I wrote an example on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/lHjtP).

---

Your first approach might be confusing to future readers of your code. They might think that the code was there twice by accident. Using a function like this avoids this confusing.

The performance hit would be very minimal, if even > 0, since the compiler is likely to inline the function and completely optimize out the loop for small `times`'. If you're worried about performance, benchmark first.